# PageController not working in release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm not sure if anyone could understand this but my PageController is not changing pages programmatically in release mode (working completely fine in debug mode), no stack trace, no weird log (tried with flutter logs.

Code is something like this:

```
final controller = PageController();

PageView(
   controller: controller,
   allowImplicitScrolling: false,
   children: listOfWidgets,
)
```

And I'm controller the page from after layout state mixin's overridden method 'afterLayout(BuildContext context) {}'

this is something like this:

```
   @override
   void afterLayout(BuildContext context) async {
      String data = await getSomeData();
      if(data=="") {
         controller.animateToPage(1, Duration(seconds:1), Curves.ease);
      } else {
         Navigator.push(context, Page);
   }
```

All this is working fine in debug and profile mode, but not in release.

Comment: It's possible that `await getSomeData()` is throwing an error that is handled and not output to the console. Likely something about getting that data that is different between prod and the other environments?

Comment: @daddygames No actually the code is progressing through that pass and to the if condition, tried with breakpoints and it's even going till the animateToPage method, and I've also handled the exception here too just in case and printed the exception